# why won't my image show?

Tags: html, css

My image is saved in the same folder tree or whatever that is called as my webpage, and it won't load. It's probably something really simple but I can't figure it out. Any hint would be appreciated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML     4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    http-equiv="content-type">
    <title>website</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen, print, projection">

    body{
         background-image:url('C:\Users\blah\Desktop\webdesign\randompicture.png');
    }


    </style> 
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using relative paths, if your picture is in the same directory as your html file, simply write:

```
background-image: url(randompicture.png);
```

Also, you don't need apostrophes in the `url()` notation of CSS.

If you put your rules into a separate CSS file, the path should be relative to the CSS file, not the HTML.

Comment: Thank you that worked, I'm a begginer and learning as you can tell. btw say it was in a different folder, how would I use that image? because previously the picture was in another folder and I used the full path xxx/xxx/xxx/pic.png and it wouldn't work.

Comment: @javi if the HTML is in `webdesign`, and the image is in `webdesign/static/images` you can just write `url(static/images/randompicture.png)`.

Answer (score 3):

instead of `C:\Users\blah\Desktop\webdesign\randompicture.png'`

use relative path if your htm file is in `webdesign` folder randompicture.png

use `background-image: url(randompicture.png);`

if the html file is on desktop

use `background-image: url('./webdesign/randompicture.png');`

Answer (score 1):

if the image is in the same folder, use:

```
body
{
   background-image: url('randompicture.png');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! If it was in a different folder, how would I use that image? because previously the picture was in another folder and I used the full path xxx/xxx/xxx/pic.png and it wouldn't work.

Comment: Always try to use a relative path. When the image is in a different folder: background-image: url('../your-image.png'); or background-image: url('images/your-image.png');